# ¿Cómo crear una aplicación para una NAS en ASUSTOR app center?

Tags: task

Me gustaría preguntar a las personas que tiene algún conocimiento sobre los productos  **NAS** de **ASUSTOR**.

Quiero crear un aplicación para el sistema que tienen las **NAS** de **ASUSTOR**, pero no encuentro información como donde puedo empezar o que lenguajes de programación se pueden utilizar.

Le agradecería mucho a la persona que me pueda ayudar con estas dudas.